# Python - TWAIN for windows not working

Tags: python, windows, twain, epson

I have this document scanner connected via USB 2.0 to Windows 8.1 Pro machine, using TWAIN protocol i need to now scan it.

[image]

Python27 and Python Twain is installed but when i execute code it keep failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ImportError: No module named twain

Copy **twain.pyd** to **Python27\Lib\site-packages**.

> IndentationError: expected an indented block

Python is indentation-sensitive. Check your code and fix indentation.